# Puppet Enterprise Installer - Validating page stuck

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am trying to install `puppet-enterprise-2016.1.2-ubuntu-14.04-amd64.tar` on Ubuntu 14.04. I get to the browser gui installer. I open the server FQDN with port 3000 in a browser, select monothilic, and on the same server. I fill in the FQDN name, DNS alias, and console admin password, and then click submit. Then I get to the `Puppet Enterprise Installer - Validating` page. After that nothing is displaying. It looks like it is stuck. The page should display `validating RAM, memory` etc., but it does not show any details. It only shows this in the browser page:

```
View the answer files we've just generated 

master.puppet.vm   

You can find the installer answer file at '/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/share/installer/answers' on ec2-35-163-72-135.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com, but note that this answer file is overwritten each time you run the installer.
```

I checked the `/var/log/puppetLabs` log file but there is no info.

How can I know what is the problem?

Comment: It sounds like something happened with the installer where it bypassed the validation part and went straight to the end. Since you have Puppet Enterprise support, I would recommend putting in a ticket for this soon since 2016.1 is EOL at the end of the year.

Comment: Matt, even I tried of puppet-enterprise-2016.4.2-ubuntu-16.04-amd64.tar on ubuntu-16 , i do see the same issue..

Comment: My recommendation was to put in a ticket to your support team at Puppet, not to try a different version.

Comment: I have posted this but no response from community.It has not bypasses the validation page. its on validation page.Heading is "Puppet Enterprise Installer - Validating". I am feeling somewhere I am doing wrong, but don't know.

Comment: It worked after some time....!!!!